# Need help in resolving the simple cocos2d error

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am using following code to render the image on screen

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Player.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];     
    }
    return self;
}
```

when I ran the code following error is coming

```
continue
2011-07-11 19:25:58.220 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.0-rc3
2011-07-11 19:25:58.229 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2011-07-11 19:25:58.407 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: OS version: 4.3.1 (0x04030100)
2011-07-11 19:25:58.411 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination         Technologies
2011-07-11 19:25:58.415 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 535
2011-07-11 19:25:58.418 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1       IMGSGX535-58.6
2011-07-11 19:25:58.423 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
2011-07-11 19:25:58.427 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2011-07-11 19:25:58.430 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2011-07-11 19:25:58.434 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2011-07-11 19:25:58.437 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2011-07-11 19:25:58.441 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2011-07-11 19:25:58.444 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2011-07-11 19:25:58.447 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2011-07-11 19:25:58.450 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : NO
2011-07-11 19:25:58.454 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2011-07-11 19:25:58.457 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2011-07-11 19:25:58.554 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil
2011-07-11 19:25:58.558 testcellapp[441:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:Player.png in CCTextureCache
2011-07-11 19:25:58.564 testcellapp[441:707] *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:], /Users/shahbazali/Documents/testcellapp/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:408
2011-07-11 19:25:58.601 testcellapp[441:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x32c3064f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x31da4c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x32c30491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
    3   Foundation                          0x318a2573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 62
    4   testcellapp                         0x00067c1c -[CCNode addChild:] + 196
    5   testcellapp                         0x000033ec -[HelloWorldLayer init] + 400
    6   testcellapp                         0x00066ca0 +[CCNode node] + 76
    7   testcellapp                         0x000031fc +[HelloWorldLayer scene] + 100
    8   testcellapp                         0x00002aac -[testcellappAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 1028
    9   UIKit                               0x32f6a85d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 832
    10  UIKit                               0x32f64b65 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 272
    11  UIKit                               0x32f397d7 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
    12  UIKit                               0x32f39215 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
    13  UIKit                               0x32f38c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x31118e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x32c07a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x32c0983f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
    17  CoreFound
```

Please help why this error is coming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[CCNode addChild:]` uses an `NSAssert` to let you know that the argument is not allowed to be nil.
Make sure `player` is not nil.

Also note the lines in the log before the crash.

> cocos2d: CCTexture2D. **Can't create Texture. UIImage is nil** 
>   cocos2d: **Couldn't add image:Player.png** in CCTextureCache